# What is the point of the blue grid on the Normandy?

Tags: mass-effect-3

On the Normandy, there is a section on the war room level (level 2) where you have to walk through a blue grid that scans you. What is the point of this grid? What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In game, this is meant to be a security check point, as it separates the rest of the ship with the war room and the security link to earth.

Out of game, I think this is a fancy transition zone as it sometimes takes a long time to be able to 'cross' it.

Comment: Also, I think it's a hidden load spot.

Comment: @Fredy31 Yeah, that's exactly what the second graf of the answer is saying.

Comment: I tought it was not clear enough.

Comment: It's certainly annoying - but then again, very nice place to hide a loading zone.